# Trigger ListView's OnClickListener in a TabActivity?

Tags: android, listactivity, tabactivity

I've searched around for a while now to try to find a solution to this problem, but none of them have worked for me. I have a tab setup which displays tab activities. I'm trying to use a OnClickListener in ListView to catch click events in a list, but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance for helping!

```
public class Ettan extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ettan);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.nyhetslista,
                        new String[] { "rubrik", "kategori" },
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(false);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not the `getApplicationContext()` that's acting up? Try using `Ettan.class` instead, just to be sure!

Comment: When using Ettan.class:

The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Ettan>, String, int)

Comment: My bad, I meant `Ettan.this`!

Comment: Bump... The problem is that the ListView posts gets unfocused when I click on them. It works to mark them with the arrow keys, but never clicking on them...

Comment: That description makes me think that some child-view is stealing focus. Are you using any checkboxes or similar "form"-elements?

Comment: No, that's the thing. I don't...

Comment: I still think that the issue is focus-related, would you mind trying to create an `onClick(View v)` and setting it on a Button/TextView (via xml) on the same "level" as the ListView?

Comment: I put a button next to my ListView and the onClick method worked there. What does that mean? :/
By the way, clicking on/in the ListView still doesn't do anything. Not even clicking the button.

Comment: I'm successfully getting clicks on a ListView inside a TabActivity, here's my "onListItemClickListener": http://codepad.org/IVIiANWs

Comment: However, I'm guessing that your tabs are loaded via an intent and not just by setting the content to a layout?

Comment: Also: http://pastebin.com/QSni5CE9

Comment: Yes, the tabs are loaded via an intent. You said you got it to work with a ListView in a TabActivity? I just tried that, but I got problems with it saying that it couldn't find R.id.tabhost. An Activity worked, but it's the same issue with the ListView. I can use the emulator to mark list items, but when I press the middle button or return, onItemClick isn't called...
Can you give me a more detailed example of code when you got it to work?

Comment: Here you go, hope that it helps out! https://github.com/ninetwozero/BF3-Battlelog/blob/master/src/com/ninetwozero/battlelog/ProfileView.java